# remove default radio button checkbox when using a custom selector

Tags: android, android-layout

I am attempting to style a radio button and so I created a selector.  Everything works except the standard radio button image still shows up.  How do I remove the default radio button checkbox.  I tried assigning the drawable to an empty string, but the compiler does not like it.

Here is the code of one of my selector states:

```
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#808080"
            android:centerColor="#2F2F2F"
            android:endColor="#2F2F2F"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/black" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the drawable all together? Can you replace it with something that fits your needs?

Comment: I want the functionality of a radio button, but want it to look like a button.  Specifically I want to have two buttons side by side that toggle one another.  One of the buttons appears down and the other up.  Is there a better solution than where I am heading?

Comment: I actually found that I can remove the default checkbox with the following `android:button="@null"`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found that I cannot remove the default radiobutton checkbox in the selector.  I found that it can be removed by assigning the "button" property to null, in either the style or the definition of the radiobutton itself.

Here is an example using a style.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/myRadioButton"
    style="@style/RadioButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/custom_radio_button"/>

<style name="RadioButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/radiobutton_selector</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
</style>
```

radiobutton_selector defines a selector that draws the button in its different checked states.  Here is the checked state:

```
<item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/titleButtonCheckedGradientLight"
            android:centerColor="@color/titleButtonCheckedGradientDark"
            android:endColor="@color/titleButtonCheckedGradientDark"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/titleButtonBorder" />
        <corners
            android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: your code does not seem to get radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() function.........

Comment: best answer so far

Answer (score 41):

Set the button value to null in layout XML

```
android:button="@null"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I had found this also as you can see from my Feb 15 2012 comment in my question.

Comment: for campatibility of android below 5 also add  
app:buttonCompat="@null"

Comment: @HamedJaliliani your comment was really helpful to my cause. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna set custom background to RadioButton programmatically, then you can set it like this,

```
radioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);
radioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_custom_drawable);
```